# Edits which simply change the way URLs are referenced

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I've had an edit suggested to [one of my answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1250260/have-a-multiple-drive-computer-what-drive-do-i-need-to-image-backup/1250269#1250269) which changes the hyperlinks I put in from:

> http://wwww.somewebsite.com/question_about_something.html

to:

> [Question about something | Some website](http://wwww.somewebsite.com/question_about_something.html)

Initially I accepted the change because I couldn't really think of a reason why it makes the page any worse. In fact, knowing the destination website and title might be useful.

However I was then taken to the edit queue where it appears that this user has made quite a few of the same edits to various answers.

Is there some standard formatting of links which I'm not aware of? Or is this just a case of someone making minor edits for the sake of it? What would others have done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick look at his edits looks like he's just fixing up links and formatting. The quality of these edits at a glance seem... ok, and he's actually taking the effort to write good edit reasons. Seems fine to me!

While there's no official standard formatting, he dosen't seem to be doing *that* many edits a day, and well, its an improvement.

> Initially I accepted the change because I couldn't really think of a reason why it makes the page any worse. In fact, knowing the destination website and title might be useful.

Which is utterly awesome and is worth doing if you come across a bare link.

So, if it respects your answer and makes it better and OP isn't hitting like a dozen edits a day, there's no harm (quite the contrary - it makes your post better).

Comment: Sounds like something which could be easily automated. It could even double up as a dead link checker.